# How to check if a target will be run?

Tags: make, gnu-make

I know that the variable `MAKECMDGOALS` In GNU Make will contain the names of *final* goals for the run, i.e. the targets included on the command line.

However I'd like to check if a target will be made, whether as a goal **or as an intermediate step**. Is this possible without recursive make runs or some other complicated mechanism? I'd prefer a portable solution (at least to Darwin) but GNU-specific answers are fine too.

Comment: is it possible to run in dry-run mode? make -n?

Comment: @user3589054 I mean from within Make itself.